# Revised console-based quiz application

Tags: c++, object-oriented, design-patterns

This question is a follow up to my previous question, link to the post can be found [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/252125/console-based-quiz-application/252148#252148). I really appreciate the reviewers especially @Edward's review. They highlighted great points which were considered whilst refactoring the codebase.

## OVERVIEW

This project is a console-based quiz application. It can be constructed from a `xml` file and a `std::vector` of quiz objects. `Quiz Application` was designed as one of the ways in which users of the class `Quiz` might program a quiz application. This insinuates that `Quiz Application` might be programmed in another way depending on the taste of the user.

## AIM

1. I aim to practice object-oriented programming.
2. I aim to improve my ability to produce robust and usable classes.
3. I aim to solidify my knowledge on STL containers and generic algorithms.

## MAJOR CONCERN

I don't know if this fits for code review site or maybe should be posted on a different stack exchange site. I planned on persisting objects of type `QuizApplication`. `SOLID` design principle requires that classes do one thing and do it very well. `QuizApplication` so far, generates quiz and grades quiz, does it make any sense for it to also persist an object of its type or should the job be moved to a different class, keeping in mind that the storage facility might change in the near future?

### Quiz.h

```cpp
#ifndef QUIZ_H_
#define QUIZ_H_

#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <map>

struct Quiz 
{
    friend std::ostream& operator<<( std::ostream &os, const Quiz &quiz );
    Quiz();
    Quiz( const std::string &question, const std::vector<std::string>& options, \
        const std::string& answer, const std::vector<std::string>& tag );
    bool operator==( const Quiz& quiz );
    bool operator==( const Quiz& quiz ) const;
    std::string question_;
    std::string answer_;
    std::vector<std::string> tag_;
    std::map<char, std::string, std::less<char>> options_;
};

#endif
```

### Quiz.cpp

```cpp
#include "Quiz.h"

#include <iostream>

Quiz::Quiz( const std::string &question, const std::vector<std::string>& options, \
const std::string& answer, const std::vector<std::string>& tag )
     : question_{ question }, answer_{ answer }, tag_{ tag } 
    {
        int alphabelt = 65;
        for( const auto item : options )
            options_.insert( { char( alphabelt++ ) , item } );
    } 

std::ostream& operator<<( std::ostream &os, const Quiz &quiz )
{
    for( const auto &item : quiz.tag_ )
        os << "[" << item << "]"; 

    os << '\n' << quiz.question_ << '\n';

    for( const auto item : quiz.options_ )
        os << item.first << ". " << item.second << '\n';

    return os;
}

bool Quiz::operator==( const Quiz& quiz )
{
    if( question_ != quiz.question_ ) return false;
    if( answer_ != quiz.answer_ ) return false;
    if( options_ != quiz.options_ ) return false;
    if( tag_ != quiz.tag_ ) return false;

    return true;
}

bool Quiz::operator==( const Quiz& quiz ) const
{
    if( question_ != quiz.question_ ) return false;
    if( answer_ != quiz.answer_ ) return false;
    if( options_ != quiz.options_ ) return false;
    if( tag_ != quiz.tag_ ) return false;

    return true;
}
```

### QuizApplication.h

```cpp
#ifndef QUIZAPPLICATION_H_
#define QUIZAPPLICATION_H_

#include "Quiz.h"

#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <unordered_set>
#include <map>

struct QuizHash
{
    size_t operator()( const Quiz &quiz ) const
    {
       return std::hash<std::string>()( quiz.question_ );
    }
};

class QuizApplication
{
    friend std::ostream& operator<<( std::ostream &os, const QuizApplication& app );

    public:
        QuizApplication( const std::vector<Quiz>& quiz )
        : quiz_container_{ quiz } {}
        explicit QuizApplication( const std::string &filename ) { read_xml( filename); };
        QuizApplication& add_quiz( const Quiz& quiz );
        QuizApplication& remove_quiz( const Quiz& quiz );
        void start_quiz() const;
        std::vector<Quiz>::iterator get( Quiz& quiz );
        std::vector<Quiz>::const_iterator get( const Quiz& quiz ) const;

        static int number_of_quiz_to_ask;

    private:
        std::vector<Quiz> quiz_container_;

        void read_xml( const std::string& filename );
        std::unordered_set<Quiz, QuizHash> generate_quiz_set() const;
        unsigned grade_quiz( std::multimap<char, Quiz> &quiz_choice ) const;
};

#endif
```

### QuizApplication.cpp

```cpp
#include "QuizApplication.h"

#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <random>
#include <map>

#include <boost/property_tree/ptree.hpp>
#include <boost/property_tree/xml_parser.hpp>

int QuizApplication::number_of_quiz_to_ask = 0;

void QuizApplication::read_xml( const std::string& filename )
{
    namespace pt = boost::property_tree;

    pt::ptree tree;
    pt::xml_parser::read_xml( filename, tree );

    Quiz quiz_obj 
    {   "",
        {},
        "",
        {}
    };
    
    for( auto &quiz_item : tree.get_child( "quizlist" ) )
    { 
        int alphabelt = 65;
        if( quiz_item.first == "quiz" )
        {
            quiz_obj.question_ = quiz_item.second.get<std::string>("question");
            quiz_obj.answer_ = quiz_item.second.get<std::string>("answer");
            
            auto option_list = quiz_item.second.get_child("optionlist");
            for( auto &item : option_list )
            {
                quiz_obj.options_.insert( { char( alphabelt++ ), item.second.data() } );
            }

            auto tag_list = quiz_item.second.get_child("taglist");
            for( auto &item : tag_list )
            {
                quiz_obj.tag_.push_back( item.second.data() );
            }
        }
        quiz_container_.push_back( quiz_obj );
        quiz_obj.options_ = {};
        quiz_obj.tag_ = {};
    }
}

QuizApplication& QuizApplication::add_quiz( const Quiz& quiz )
{
    quiz_container_.push_back( quiz );

    return *this;
}

QuizApplication& QuizApplication::remove_quiz( const Quiz& quiz )
{ 
    auto iter = get( quiz );
    if( iter != quiz_container_.cend() )
        quiz_container_.erase( iter );

    return *this;
}

std::vector<Quiz>::iterator QuizApplication::get( Quiz& quiz )
{
    auto iter = std::find_if( quiz_container_.begin(), quiz_container_.end(), \
                            [quiz]( Quiz& this_quiz ) { return ( this_quiz == quiz ); } );
    return iter;
};

std::vector<Quiz>::const_iterator QuizApplication::get( const Quiz& quiz ) const
{
    auto iter = std::find_if( quiz_container_.cbegin(), quiz_container_.cend(), \
                            [quiz]( const Quiz& this_quiz ) { return ( this_quiz == quiz ); } );
    return iter;
}

std::ostream& operator<<( std::ostream &os, const QuizApplication& app )
{
    for( const auto& item : app.quiz_container_ )
        os << item << '\n';

    return os;
}

void QuizApplication::start_quiz() const
{
    std::unordered_set<Quiz, QuizHash> quiz_set = generate_quiz_set();
    std::multimap<char, Quiz> quiz_choice;

    for( const auto &item : quiz_set )
    {
        std::cout << '\n' << item << "? ";
        char choice;
        std::cin >> choice;
        quiz_choice.insert( { toupper( choice), item } );
    }

    unsigned score = grade_quiz( quiz_choice );
    char choice;
    std::cout << "Do you want your grade? (y/n)";
    std::cin >> choice;
    if( choice == 'y' ) std::cout << "Your score is " << score << std::endl;
    else std::cout << "See you some other time" << std::endl;
}

std::unordered_set<Quiz, QuizHash> QuizApplication::generate_quiz_set() const
{
    std::unordered_set<Quiz, QuizHash> quiz_set;
    std::default_random_engine engine( static_cast<unsigned>( time( nullptr) ) );
    std::uniform_int_distribution<unsigned> random_int( 0, quiz_container_.size() - 1 );

    for( int i = 0; i != number_of_quiz_to_ask; )
    {
        unsigned index = random_int( engine );
        auto insert_return = quiz_set.insert( quiz_container_[ index ] );
        if( insert_return.second )
            ++i;
        else 
            continue;
    }

    return quiz_set;
}

unsigned QuizApplication::grade_quiz( std::multimap<char, Quiz> &quiz_choice ) const
{
    unsigned score = 0;
    for( const auto& item : quiz_choice )
    {
        if( item.second.options_.at( item.first ) == item.second.answer_ ) 
            ++score;
    }
    return score;
}
```

### quiz.xml

```
<quizlist>
    <quiz>
        <question>Pointer-based code is complex and error-prone—the slightest omissions or oversights
can lead to serious memory-access violations and memory-leak errors that the compiler
will warn you about.</question>
        <optionlist>
            <option>True</option>
            <option>False</option>
        </optionlist>
        <answer>False</answer>
        <taglist>
            <tag>C++</tag>
            <tag>Programming</tag>
        </taglist>
    </quiz>

    <quiz>
        <question>deques offer rapid insertions and deletions at front or back and direct access to any element.</question>
        <optionlist>
            <option>False</option>
            <option>True</option>
        </optionlist>
        <answer>True</answer>
        <taglist>
            <tag>C++</tag>
            <tag>Programming</tag>
        </taglist>
    </quiz>
</quizlist>
```

### main.cpp

```cpp
#include <iostream>

#include "Quiz.h"
#include "QuizApplication.h"

int main()
{
    QuizApplication::number_of_quiz_to_ask = 2;

    Quiz quiz_obj
    {
        "What is my name?",
        { "Samuel", "Kingsley", "Paul", "John" },
        "Samuel",
        { "Name" }
    };

    QuizApplication app { "quiz.xml" };
    app.add_quiz( quiz_obj );
    app.start_quiz();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### `Quiz` class:

`class Quiz` - I would probably call this class `Question` instead. In English a "quiz" would be the entire set of questions.

---

```
Quiz();
```

It looks like the default constructor is declared, but not defined. We should do `Quiz() { }` or `Quiz() = default;`

---

```
Quiz( const std::string &question, const std::vector<std::string>& options, \
    const std::string& answer, const std::vector<std::string>& tag );
```

It's fine to split function definitions across multiple lines. There's no need for the `\`.

---

```
bool operator==( const Quiz& quiz );
bool operator==( const Quiz& quiz ) const;
```

We don't need both of these. A `const` member function can be called on both a `const` and non-`const` `Quiz` object, so we only need the `const` version.

Alternatively, we could make this a free function that takes two `Quiz` objects:

```
bool operator==(const Quiz& a, const Quiz& b);
```

---

We store the answer string twice in `Quiz` - once in the `answer_` variable, and once in the `options_` map. We only need to store the `char` key of the correct answer in the `answer_` variable.

---

```
    int alphabelt = 65;
    for( const auto item : options )
        options_.insert( { char( alphabelt++ ) , item } );
```

Typo: in English it's `alphabet`.

We could avoid the cast from `int` to `char` and make it a little clearer by doing: `char alphabet = 'A';`. `char` is an integer type too, so we can increment it.

We probably want to use `const auto& item` in the range-based for loop, instead of `const auto item` to avoid an unnecessary copy.

---

Since we're using alphabet letters to refer to questions, we should check somewhere that we don't have more questions in a quiz than characters in the alphabet.

---

### `QuizHash` class:

Using a hash of the entire question string as a storage key is probably not a good idea. (It's going to be slow to compute the hash value, and we have to know the entire question string to find a question).

I don't think the `set` is actually necessary here, we could just use a `vector`.

---

### `QuizApplication` class:

```
    std::vector<Quiz>::iterator get( Quiz& quiz );
    std::vector<Quiz>::const_iterator get( const Quiz& quiz ) const;
```

These functions are only needed inside the `QuizApplication` (and outside code has no way to access the `quiz_container_`) so they could be private.

---

```
    static int number_of_quiz_to_ask;
```

`number_of_questions_to_ask` would be a more accurate name.

---

```
Quiz quiz_obj 
{   "",
    {},
    "",
    {}
};
```

We could use the default constructor (assuming it's defined - see above): `Quiz quiz_obj;`

---

```
    int alphabelt = 65;
```

Same as in `Quiz` class (`alphabet`, use a `char` - see above).

---

```
    quiz_obj.options_ = {};
    quiz_obj.tag_ = {};
```

We could avoid having to reset the variable every loop iteration by declaring `quiz_obj` inside the loop.

---

```
auto iter = std::find_if( quiz_container_.begin(), quiz_container_.end(), \
                        [quiz]( Quiz& this_quiz ) { return ( this_quiz == quiz ); } );
return iter;
```

We have an `operator==` for `Quiz`, so we should able to use `std::find(quiz_container_.begin(), quiz_container_.end(), quiz);` instead.

Again, there's no need for the `\`.

---

### Generating the quiz set

```
std::unordered_set<Quiz, QuizHash> QuizApplication::generate_quiz_set() const
```

We don't want to duplicate all the `Quiz` data when generating the question set. We can generate a set of random indices into `quiz_container_` instead, something like:

```
std::vector<std::size_t> QuizApplication::generate_quiz_set() const
{
    std::vector<std::size_t> out(quiz_container.size(), 0);
    std::iota(out.begin(), out.end(), 0); // out = { 0, 1, 2, 3 ... quiz_container.size() - 1 }
    
    std::default_random_engine engine(static_cast<unsigned>(time(nullptr)));
    std::shuffle(out.begin(), out.end(), engine); // shuffle the indices
    
    out.resize(std::min(number_of_quiz_to_ask, out.size())); // chop off the ones we don't need
    
    return out;
}
```

---

### Running the quiz:

```
void QuizApplication::start_quiz() const
{
    std::unordered_set<Quiz, QuizHash> quiz_set = generate_quiz_set();
    std::multimap<char, Quiz> quiz_choice;

    for( const auto &item : quiz_set )
    {
        std::cout << '\n' << item << "? ";
        char choice;
        std::cin >> choice;
        quiz_choice.insert( { toupper( choice), item } );
    }

    ...
```

We should check that the `choice` character is a valid option for the question, and ask the user again if it isn't. Currently, we'll throw an exception when grading the quiz later.

Again, I don't think we need the `set` or the `multimap`. If we use a `vector` to store the generated quiz set, we could simply use another `vector` to store the choices:

```
void QuizApplication::start_quiz() const
{
    std::vector<std::size_t> quiz_set = generate_quiz_set();
    std::vector<char> quiz_choices;
    
    for( const auto &item : quiz_set )
    {
        std::cout << '\n' << item << "? ";
        char choice;
        std::cin >> choice;
        // todo: check choice is a valid option!!!
        quiz_choices.push_back(choice);
    }
    
    ...
```

Now `quiz_choices[i]` contains the response to `quiz_set[i]`, where the value stored in `quiz_set[i]` is the index to the `Quiz` in `quiz_container_`. So now marking the quiz looks something like:

```
unsigned score = 0;
for (auto i = std::size_t{ 0 }; i != quiz_choices.size(); ++i)
{
    auto const& choice = quiz_choices[i];
    auto const& index = quiz_set[i];
    
    if (choice == quiz_container_[index].answer_) // assuming we change answer_ to be a `char` instead of the full string
        ++score;
}
```

---

Comment: Good points. I actually preferred a `set` to a `vector `cause I want to generate only unique questions. Secondly, if I consider renaming `Quiz`  to `Question`, then it would make no sense to add data member `answer` to it.

Comment: Moreso, a user might mistakenly add a quiz object twice into the container, if I had used indices for generating the question set, their is a chance of having non-unique questions.

Comment: @theProgrammer The renaming of Quiz to Question and QuizApplication to Quiz seems to be in line with some of the answers from the previous version of the question.